# How can I have an .mp3 file on my site open in an app that plays MP3's?

Tags: iphone, url, web, uri

I publish MP3s on my site. Since my audience prefers to listen to those MP3s on their iPhones, they tend to 1) download my files, 2) open up iTunes, 3) find the app folder, and 4) drag my MP3 to the audio app of their choice.

It's a tough process.

But they don't want to listen to my MP3s is their iPhone's browser and I can't get all my MP3s into a podcast.

So, I was wondering if there's a URL scheme that would let my readers, click a link on my site and have it automatically open the corresponding MP3 in a program like Apple's Podcast or Downcast or even send it to Dropbox.

Comment: What happens if you use "Content-Type: audio/mpeg"?

Comment: Paul, I'm not sure how to do that. What happens now is that my MP3's are played within the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This question sounds interesting, the answer is you must known the third app's scheme which contains url parameter, also the the third app must support playing mp3 file online and is already launched in the user's iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Yep!

There's the "music://" URL schema that opens iPod/Music app. I just don't know if it's valid to content from web, but you can try it out.

Check more information here:
http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Music_.2F_iPod

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it, but it links to the music app and says 'no content.' I think that URL schema is for opening music that's in the  iTunes store.